# Extracting href from <a> which has a download option using python

Tags: html, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the contents of a  tag. Here is a example of the html:

```
<p><a href="https://requiredlink.com" download>Download<span class="caret">
```

Here is what I'm doing:

```
r = requests.get("https://abc.efg.questions").content
    html_obj = html.fromstring(r)   
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r)
    for a in soup.find_all("a", text=re.compile("Download")):
        print a['href']
```

The print statement returns nothing. Is there something wrong with what I did?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It fails because there is a `<span>` tag inside `<a>`, therefore the object's **[`.string()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-string-argument)** method returns `None`, you can rewrite your list with a list comprehension to make it work, something like:

```
>>> for a in [s for s in soup.find_all("a") if s.text == "Download"]:
        print(a['href'])    

https://requiredlink.com
```